# Invalid syntax error when following "Creating your first ubuntu app" video

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, quickly

```
$ quickly run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/mybrowser", line 32, in <module>
    import mybrowser
  File "/home/michael/mybrowser/mybrowser/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from mybrowser import MybrowserWindow
  File "/home/michael/mybrowser/mybrowser/MybrowserWindow.py", line 39
    def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self,widget):  
 ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was up to 26th minute on this Youtube video:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg&feature=g-u-u

When I was to type `quickly run`, I got this invalid syntax. Is there something I've done wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to tell where the syntax error lies without seeing your code. Would you mind publishing your code somewhere, as described on http://askubuntu.com/questions/154129/how-to-publish-my-code-online-for-someone-to-help-me-with-review/ ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is  very important in python. Here you typed code without proper indentation. Retry with proper indentation. If it still doesn't work post the contents of `Mybrowser.py` in your question.