# Strangely quickly runs but debugger crashes with no exception

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, glib, python-2.7

Firstly, strangely `quickly run` on my app runs fine and i believe i have made no changes to the source since quickly debug was working (proclaiming it's not user error is distasteful, I know!).

winpdb itself crashes while my app is initializing inside the boilerplate *Window.py* inside `Gio.Settings()`.

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'net.launchpad.cookety-app' is not installed.
```

I have checked folder *data/glib-2.0/schemas* and all is as it was when I created project with schemas present.

I have stepped through the code right inside */usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py*, and found out that `Settings.__init__()` is where it crashes.

No exceptions, no debugger pausing, just a straight connection lost and winpdb closes thus making it insane for me to even get to the line of code that creates the problem.. most frustrating. Please help!

Comment: Could you give us some more details so that we can better help you? It'd be great if you could point us to the code, you might find this useful if it's not yet online: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154129/how-can-i-publish-my-project-code-online-so-someone-can-help-me-with-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winpdb can't locate the glib settings schema which is used for storing preferences. For example, if you look in the Preferences.py file which Quickly auto-generates, you'll see a call to Gio.Settings("net.launchpad.XXX") which retrieves any locally stored preferences for your application, based on the defined schema.

The [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.32/glib-compile-schemas.html) for glib-compile-schemas tells us that schemas are searched for in paths matching glib-2.0/schemas/ under the directories in XDG_DATA_DIRS. So, you have a choice. You can either formally install the schema as so:

```
sudo ln -s $PWD/data/glib-2.0/schemas/net.launchpad.XXX /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

Or, much more simply, you can set the variable at execution time:

```
XDG_DATA_DIRS=$XDG_DATA_DIRS:data quickly debug
```

Coincidentally, the same advice applies to running your application outside of Quickly, e.g.

```
XDG_DATA_DIRS=$XDG_DATA_DIRS:data python bin/XXX
```

Note that the above commands assume you're in the root dir of your project, as you probably are if you're using Quickly.