# Custom scrips into quickly project

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

How can I add my custom .py file to a quickly project? I'm porting my actual, from scratch project and I have two Python scripts: `virtuam` and `vui.py`. I copied vui.py to the virtuam folder and tried this:

```
from virtuam import vui
```

but not working. So, where can I copy it? And how do I import it?

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` in your `virtuam` folder?

Comment: If you could give us some more information, we'd be able to better help you. Could you show us your current code? You can do it like this if you want: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154129/how-can-i-publish-my-project-code-online-so-someone-can-help-me-with-it

Comment: I removed it, but I have a backup. Why?

Comment: There is no need for the 'NOTE: THIS QUESTION WAS ANSWERED BY MYSELF, SO PLEASE DON'T POST' note. It's perfectly valid to have multiple answers. Who knows, perhaps someone can offer an even better answer! :)

Comment: Oh! I didn't think that... :P Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple (but not obvious):

1. Copy the script into the `<project>_lib` folder.
2. Add the script functions in the `__init__.py` file:

   `from . <script> import <function>`
3. Now add the function in the main script:

   `from <project>_lib import <function>`

   If you want to call the function, just type `<function>(<options>)`

Thanks to [@mhall119](https://askubuntu.com/users/4997/mhall119) for his question/answer! :P

Comment: A better approach would be to copy your code to the `<project>` folder instead of `<project>_lib`, which is for private and common modules and should generally not be modified unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I like it. Maybe that should be Quickly's slogan: `simple (but not obvious)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy, for example your vui.py script to /quickly/project_name/project_name folder, where is stored python code generated initialy from quickly, for example project_nameWindow.py and others ,then you can import with

```
import vui
```

or

```
from vui import *
```

Comment: Not working: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/virtuam", line 15, in <module> import vui ImportError: No module named vui`