# Translating quickly application

Tags: application-development, quickly, development, translation, gettext

I created an application using `quickly create ubuntu-application myapp`.
Then I created translations and created deb package `quickly package` to install and test it. When I run myapp all strings from glade files were translated but all strings from code were not translated. What's this? How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this. I must use `locale.gettext` instead of `gettext`. I don't know what the difference is, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you need to mark all your strings for translation by enclosing them in `_()`. E.g.:

```
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.textdomain('yourappname')

some_string = 'This is not a translatable string'
some_other_string = _('This is a translatable string')
```

Notice the gettext statements above, which Quickly puts in each source file. You'll need to add them to any source file that contains translatable strings.

Comment: Yes I add it but it's no result

Comment: In that case, please be more detailed in your question. It might be useful to post the code online to I or someone else can have a look at it and better be able to help rather than guessing. You might find this useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154129/how-can-i-publish-my-project-code-online-so-someone-can-help-me-with-it

Comment: I published code at Launchpad http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~denimnumber1/quickly-ide/trunk/files